# Socket.BeginConnect vs Socket.Connect

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, connect

I want to connect to a `Socket` but I found 2 different connection methods: `BeginConnect` and `Connect`. Does anybody knows the difference between the 2? 
Does `BeginConnect` require you to call `EndConnect` as well?

**Socket.Connect:** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ych8bz3x.aspx

**Socket.BeginConnect**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aeby4wt%28VS.80%29.aspx

Are there advantages in using one method over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation state, `Connect` is synchronous: it will block your current thread until the connection is made.

The `BeginConnect` method is asynchronous: it will do the connection in a different thread, and notify back when the connection is done. It will not block your current calling thread. You need to call `EndConnect`.